# Choose an image from the camera or gallery

Tags: android, encryption, lets-encrypt, encryption-symmetric

I have been trying to make the user to choose an image to encrypt from the camera or the gallery. but when i run the code it make me choose from the google drive, then the encrypt code not working. 
I need help. I tried every solution I could find.

here is the code:
the button choose:

```
   private void ChooseImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

the button encrypt:

```
btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EncryptImage();
                if(isEncrypted){
                    btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
                    btnEncrypt.setEnabled(false);
                    hintMsg.setText("Image Encrypted Successfully! Upload it to Cloud.");
                    hintMsg.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

                }
            }
        });
```

the encrypt methods:

```
    private void EncryptImage() {
        //Convert drawable to Bitmap

        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(EncryptImageActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_lock_outline_black_24dp);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());

        //Create file
        File outputFileEnc = new File(myDir,UUID.randomUUID().toString()+FILE_NAME_ENC);
        try {
            // Encrypt image
            AESEncrypter.encryptToFile(my_key,my_spec_key,is, new FileOutputStream(outputFileEnc));
            //Uri encFile = Uri.parse(myDir.toString());
            //filePath = Uri.parse(outputFileEnc.toString());
            isEncrypted = true;
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Encrypted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //UploadEncrypted(outputFileEnc);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
    private void UploadEncrypted(File outputFileEnc){
       // storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(filePath).child("");
        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        //Upload input stream to Firebase
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Encrypted Image ...");
        progressDialog.show();
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
             stream = new FileInputStream(outputFileEnc);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putStream(stream);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(EncryptImageActivity.this, "Upload Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(EncryptImageActivity.this, "Upload successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use this fuction :

```
    private void SelectImage(){

    final CharSequence[] items ={"Camera","Gallery","Cancel"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Add.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Image");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

            if(items[i].equals("Camera")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,Request_Camera);


            }else if (items[i].equals("Gallery")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select 
               File"),Select_File);

            }else  if(items[i].equals("Cancel")){

                dialog.dismiss();

            }



        }
    });

    builder.show();


      }
```